# Problem related to fan speed

Tags: 20.04, fan, gnome-shell-extension, system-monitor, extension

**Hello** I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I installed a system monitor extension as shown in the image I have given:- [image]

As you can see there is laptops fan speed displayed at the top. So every time I boot up the fan speed is 0 , to solve it I have to go to preferences as shown in the image and then it shows the proper reading. I installed this extension about 1 month ago and it was perfect. But now its causing this problem. I tried disabling this extension and enabling it again and setting the correct sensors and setting required time refresh and also reinstalling it but after 2-3 days it does the same behaviour . So any solutions? Thankyou Very Much for giving me your precious Time.

I installed the extension using this command :- `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor`

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop?  Is the fan running and the display just shows 0 or is it not running?

Comment: Its a laptop fan, and its running and when I go to preferences as shown in the image it shows the correct reading.@rtaft

Comment: Try instlling [via web](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/). Compared installed version that wey with the package. `jq .version ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com/metadata.json` vs `apt-cache show gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor | grep ^Version`.

Answer (score 0):

This has been mentioned in [this pull request](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/pull/581). Try updating it or wait for a new version to come out.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it as a snap. Maybe the snap code and the normal code is different. I don't know how to install it as a snap but try.

Comment: How to install it as a snap? @JohannGeorge.

Comment: I don't know even if it's a snap.

Comment: What is the name of the thing you have installed? Copy it on snapcraft.io

Comment: Can you try installing from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/

Comment: But mine look different @JohannGeorge.

Comment: put a screenshot please

Comment: I have given it in the question @JohannGeorge